# Minecraft Pocket Edition LAN Server Problems

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am using iPhone 4 and I also have samsung galaxy tab 2. At my friends house we were playing minecraft over a wifi server but when I use my own wifi the wifi server wont show up on my iphone 4 (I made the world on the galaxy tab) would it be a the configuration of my wifi that is not allowing it to work. I have a huawei E585 modem

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to happen. It's called a LAN party for a reason,

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing on a Minecraft Pocket Edition server, you can only play on it if you are connected to the wifi that the device hosting the game connected to.

Comment: we are all connected to the same wifi

Comment: You said that it works when you are both connected to your friends' wifi, which is correct. However, you are not on the same wifi when you are on yours, which is why it doesn't work.